# API for getting specific GooglePlay app reviews

Tags: android, google-api, google-play

Is it possible to user this api in order to get the reviews of a specific application?

https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/reviews

Or we can get only the reviews for my own apps in google play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right you can only get the reviews of your own apps or those that you have access to the Developer console.